# VS Code formatter for HTML emails

Tags: html, email, parsing, formatting, prettify

I'm looking for a code prettifier/formatter extension that will format HTML, specifically in the context of marketing emails.

ALL of the existing products I've seen don't take MSO conditionals into account:

[image]

...and will throw off the auto-indentation as a result (see screenshot). It might seem like a trivial issue, but it would incrementally improve my productivity to have properly indented code, rather than being visually chaotic.

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in VS code that autoformats your code on save.

```
editor.formatOnSave
```

By enabling this HTML also gets auto formatted.
It's a built-in capability so no additional extensions needed :)

Comment: Ok, does this format how the OP asked for?